# Team Foundation Server - Ensuring developers can successfully compile a checked-out solution

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS 2012 Preview for a project my friend and I are working on.

I'm working on the solution and it compiles just fine, I check it in. He pulls the solution and it has all sorts of errors. This isn't the first solution I've worked on with this type of thing happening.

The solution is large with many projects (N-Tier) including an MVC application, an SQL Database Project , Workflow activity libraries, a project for the Entity Data Model, etc.

I'm wondering if there are some kind of guidelines checklist, or option to ensure all configurations, assemblies, databases, entity models, etc are included with the check-in to ensure the solution compiles on the other end.

Comment: Consider using a build server with gated checkin. It makes it easy to define and ensure environmental requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll formalize JeffN825's answer by suggesting setting up a build for the solution that is triggered as a gated check-in.

This means that the changes are submitted to the build server and built there before the change set is actually committed. If the build fails, then you will be informed and the changes will be left checked out. This way, you ensure that the solution builds in a fresh environment.

[This page](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/build/setup-ci-build-in-vs/) provides a simple build setup guide. Gated check in is configured in the *Trigger* section

Worth to note is that if your build process requires 3rd party SDKs etc on the build computer, then you might have a hard time building using the standard Team Foundation Service build controller. You need to make ALL dll's etc required by the build process part of the workspace in source control and ensure that the projects knows where to find them.

[NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) is an excellent tool to ensure that everything you need is included and made available to the build server. If what you need is available as a NuGet package, *I strongly recommend* to use that option instead of installing it as an SDK.

In many cases, though, you'll need to have control over the build environment. In that case, it might be worth looking into how to run your own build server as a VM hosted on Azure, which enables you to install those pesky 3rd party SDKs by way of Remote Desktop. [This blog](http://bartwullems.blogspot.no/2011/10/running-your-build-server-on-azure.html) provides basic information and some nice links providing further guidance.

Comment: Are you suggesting that NuGet should be run in the build to always fetch the latest version of the packages?

Comment: Not at all, I am saying that NuGet is a nice tool to ensure that the build server finds the neccessary dependencies, rather than referencing installed 3rd party SDKs. I didn't mention anywhere that NuGet should be run as part of the build process - that would not make sense at all (the developers needs to decide which version of a NuGet package to use)

Comment: Just checking. I've heard people suggest using NuGet in the build and wanted to get this clarified.